# Error when checking target: expected shape for conv2d_transpose

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, autoencoder, deconvolution

I want to implement an auto-encoder for Faces Dataset using Keras.
I used `train_on_batch` because the dataset is too big but I am facing this problem:

```
for i in range(10):
    batch_index = 0
    while batch_index <= train_data.batch_index:
        data = train_data.next()
        result = train_result.next()
        model.train_on_batch(data[0],result[0])
        batch_index = batch_index + 1
          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent     call last)
      <ipython-input-54-d7d64e954a89> in <module>
  4         data = train_data.next()
  5         result = train_result.next()
----> 6         model.train_on_batch(data[0],result[0])
  7         batch_index = batch_index + 1

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in     train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight)
   1209             x, y,
   1210             sample_weight=sample_weight,
-> 1211             class_weight=class_weight)
   1212         if self._uses_dynamic_learning_phase():
   1213             ins = x + y + sample_weights + [1.]

     ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
787                 feed_output_shapes,
788                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 789                 exception_prefix='target')
    790 
    791             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the     `sample_weight` and

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in              standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
136                             ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have shape ' +
137                             str(shape) + ' but got array with shape ' +
--> 138                             str(data_shape))
    139     return data
    140 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_transpose_21 to      have shape (250, 250, 1) but got array with shape (250, 250, 3)
```

My model is as fellow :

```
Input_Layer = keras.Input((250,250,3))
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(20,5,activation='relu')(Input_Layer)
x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(20,2,activation = 'relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
encoded = x
x = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(20,2,activation='relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(20,5,activation= 'relu')(x)
model = keras.Model(input = Input_Layer ,output = x)
```

I am loading the images using keras `ImageDataGenerator` which load:

```
train_data = trainGenerator.flow_from_directory('lfw',batch_size=67,target_size=(250, 250))
Found 13199 images belonging to 1 classes.
```

Here is all the code

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import keras

def cutHalf(img):
    for j in range(125):
        for i in range(250):
            img[i][j][0]=1
            img[i][j][1]=1
            img[i][j][2]=1
    return img

img_width = 250
img_height = 250
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_datagen2 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,preprocessing_function=cutHalf)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'lfw',target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        class_mode=None)
train_generator2 = train_datagen2.flow_from_directory(
        'lfw',target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        class_mode=None)

def fixed_generator(generator,generator2):
    batch_index = 0
    while batch_index <= generator.batch_index:
        yield (generator.next(), generator2.next())

Input_Layer = keras.Input(shape=(img_width, img_height,3))
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(20,5,activation='relu')(Input_Layer)
x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(20,2,activation = 'relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2)(x)
encoded = x
x = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(20,2,activation='relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)
x = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(20,5,activation= 'relu')(x)
model = keras.Model(input = Input_Layer ,output = x)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(
        fixed_generator(train_generator,train_generator2),
        nb_epoch=20,
        steps_per_epoch=50
        )
```

Comment: If your data has 3 channels, your model's output must have 3 channels. Check the number of filters of the last layer.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Just change the number of filters of the last conv to 3. It's currently 1 (although you posted 20 here).

Comment: The same problem ...

Comment: The code you posted here is probably not the code you're using then...you probably think you're using one model and might be using another model... (check for typos, capital letters, specially about `x`, etc.)

Comment: I rewrited all the code and still the same problem

Comment: I still see 20 there instead of 3 (last `Conv2DTranspose` layer). --- But I believe the problem is in `'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`. Try simply `'categorical_crossentropy'`.

Comment: Important hint for performance in `cutHalf`. Use just `img[:250 , :125] = 1`

Comment: Indeed the problem was in `sparse_categorial_crossentropy` , Thank you and could you please show me why it doesn't work here?.

Comment: I don't understand "sparse" data very well, but it seems it doesn't work with entire tensors, but with indices (not sure, don't trust me here). When you use sparse crossentropy, the system usually expects data with 1 feature instead of the usual.

Answer (score 0):

I assume both `train_data.next()` and `train_result.next()` return an array of size `(1,250,250,3)`.

When I tried to run your code, I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Users/lorenzo/Documents/stackoverflow/auto_encoder.py', wdir='/Users/lorenzo/Documents/stackoverflow')
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 705, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/Users/lorenzo/Documents/stackoverflow/auto_encoder.py", line
>   43, in 
>       model.train_on_batch(onedata, oneresult)
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 1211, in train_on_batch
>       class_weight=class_weight)
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 789, in _standardize_user_data
>       exception_prefix='target')
>
> File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py",
>   line 138, in standardize_input_data
>       str(data_shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_transpose_6 to
>   have shape (250, 250, 20) but got array with shape (250, 250, 3)

It is saying that the expected target size of last Conv2DTranspose layer is `(250, 250, 20)`, but you feed into the model with an array of shape `(250, 250, 3)`.

The solution:
`x = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(20,5,activation= 'relu')(x)` should be changed to `x = keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(3,5,activation= 'relu')(x)`, so that the model's output matches your target size.

EDIT:
Just as @Daniel Möller says, the loss should be 'categorical_crossentropy', also the last layer's filter count should be 3.

Here's a sample output:

```
Found 530 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 530 images belonging to 1 classes.
D:/D_Document/Github/keras_autoencoder.py:65: UserWarning: Update your `Model` call to the Keras 2 API: `Model(inputs=Tensor("in..., outputs=Tensor("co...)`
  model = keras.Model(input = Input_Layer ,output = x)
D:/D_Document/Github/keras_autoencoder.py:78: UserWarning: The semantics of the Keras 2 argument `steps_per_epoch` is not the same as the Keras 1 argument `samples_per_epoch`. `steps_per_epoch` is the number of batches to draw from the generator at each epoch. Basically steps_per_epoch = samples_per_epoch/batch_size. Similarly `nb_val_samples`->`validation_steps` and `val_samples`->`steps` arguments have changed. Update your method calls accordingly.
  steps_per_epoch=50
D:/D_Document/Github/keras_autoencoder.py:78: UserWarning: Update your `fit_generator` call to the Keras 2 API: `fit_generator(<generator..., epochs=20, steps_per_epoch=50)`
  steps_per_epoch=50
Epoch 1/20
50/50 [==============================] - 102s 2s/step - loss: 0.6981 - acc: 0.6931
Epoch 2/20
50/50 [==============================] - 95s 2s/step - loss: 0.6406 - acc: 0.7584
Epoch 3/20
50/50 [==============================] - 92s 2s/step - loss: 0.6396 - acc: 0.7588
Epoch 4/20
50/50 [==============================] - 93s 2s/step - loss: 0.6381 - acc: 0.7543
Epoch 5/20
50/50 [==============================] - 93s 2s/step - loss: 0.6377 - acc: 0.7618
Epoch 6/20
50/50 [==============================] - 89s 2s/step - loss: 0.6357 - acc: 0.7569
Epoch 7/20
50/50 [==============================] - 91s 2s/step - loss: 0.6394 - acc: 0.7651
Epoch 8/20
50/50 [==============================] - 93s 2s/step - loss: 0.6380 - acc: 0.7660
Epoch 9/20
50/50 [==============================] - 93s 2s/step - loss: 0.6380 - acc: 0.7643
Epoch 10/20
50/50 [==============================] - 89s 2s/step - loss: 0.6399 - acc: 0.7669
```

Comment: Still the same error , the problem us that my dataset has 3 channels RGB and don't know why it is expecting 1 channel ,

Comment: Can you paste the output of  `data.shape` and `result.shape` here?

Comment: Both are  `(67,250,250,3)`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I wonder if you change the model definition before or after you ask the question. Can you check if your model definition here match that on your machine?

Comment: It is the same however i had this warning and i don't know if it is relevant to my problem `user Warning update your model call to the keras 2 API model(inputs=Tensor("in ..., outputs =Tensor("co...) this is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path() `

Comment: That warning should be ok. How about trying `model.fit_generator`? Ref: https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-image-classification-with-keras-flow-from-directory-and-generators-95f75ebe5720

Comment: Fit_generator works with labels as final outputs but my problem has images as an output or is there a way to get around this ?

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3923#issuecomment-251205420 This should work for you.

Comment: The same problem even when using generators